# Sending data to Fragment of Fragment from Activity (Activity->Fragment->Fragment) on menuItemclick

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am trying to send a data from MainActivity (on MenuItem click) to a Fragment of its Child Fragment.

I have shown an image to understand better.

[image]

I want an event to be fired in DayFragment from the MainActivity when MainActivity menuclicked.

I cannot send when the fragment is being created as you know.

Any ideas (or) code to understand the idea would be helpful.

Guys, Negative vote would neither help you nor me.

I will explain in little detail.

I am going to show a datepicker dialog fragment on menu item click on MainActivity. I need to pass the date from MainActivity -> calendarfragment - > dayfragment.

I want the date in dayfragment to other process. Thats it.

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: You can use an interface

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post the code, a lot of other code there on the corresponding files, I just need the logic. Thanks Dima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a public method inside Fragment which the Activity will call upon item selection.

From that public method, using the instance of ChildFragment, call another public method inside ChildFragment to make the magic happen!

You can use `Fragment.setTarget(Fragment fragment, int requestCode);` , just in case

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Bundle.** Here's an example:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment(); // replace your custom fragment class 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager(). beginTransaction();
bundle.putString("key","value"); // use as per your need
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(viewID,fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Bundle has put methods for lots of data types.

Then in your **Fragment**, retrieve the data **(e.g. in onCreate() method)** with:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
        int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: It cannot be used. I do not want the data when the fragment is created. I want when an action trigger on MainActivity.